# How to read String from a command Line and Not to accept an integer as an arguement

Tags: java

Am trying to get an argument from a command line using Java
For example,

> java nameOfTheProgram name1 name2

The Program should Only read string and not accept any int number 
for example :

> java nameOfTheProgram name1 5 / ----

I wanted the program to crush such that it only accepts String

I tried to use `String name1 = String.valueOf(args[0]);` -- it's working perfect, but it accepts 5 as an argument

Comment: "5" is a valid string. Instead of saying that you want to "not accept" int numbers, can you tell us what the input to do want to accept looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check for the presence of a single digit in the string:

```
String name1 = String.valueOf(args[0]);
if (name1.matches(".*[0-9].*")) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("input cannot contain numbers");
}
```

Comment: What does .*[0-9].* -- i totally understand what's inside the square bracket but i don't understand the .* that is before and after the square bracket ?

Comment: @Updy-karim It is just a regex for matching a single digit.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private  static void testString(Object data) throws Exception {
            if(data instanceof String)
             System.out.println(String.valueOf(data));
            else throw new Exception("error number");
        }

Main.testString(5);

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: error number
    at test.main.TestImage.testString(TestImage.java:18)
    at test.main.TestImage.main(TestImage.java:32)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex.

```
if(!nameOfTheProgram.matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$")) {
    // throw Exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following ways to check if the arg is number:

1) You can use `Long.valueOf`, `Double.valueOf` and catch `NumberFormatException`:

```
public class NumberFilter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (isNumber(args[0])) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number is not allowed " + args[0]);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isNumber(String value) {
        try {
            Long.valueOf(value);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

2)  Apache Commons [NumberUtils.isCreatable(String)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isCreatable-java.lang.String-)

3) Apache Commons   [StringUtils.isNumeric(CharSequence)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumeric-java.lang.CharSequence-)

4) Java regexp :

```
public static boolean isNumber(String value) {
    return Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")
                  .matcher(strNum).matches();
}
```

PS: My favorite is Apache Commons `StringUtils.isNumeric(...)`.

Comment: Your first option would fail should the text number exceed the size of long or double.